# Build a variable name in PHP out of two variables

Tags: php, variables, format

Depending on the current page, I would like to change the css of the chosen menu module and make others different, etc. All that while building dynamically the page before loading.

My problem is that I have a serie of variables going by this structure :

```
$css_(NAME_OF_MODULE)
```

To know what variable must be set , I have another variable I received in parameters of this functions, called

```
$chosen_menu
```

Say `$chosen_Menu = "C1"`, I would like to add content to `$css_C1`. Thus, what I want is to create a variable name out of 2 variables, named `$css_C1`

I have tried :

```
${$css_.$chosen_menu} = "value";
```

But it doesnt seem to work. Any clue ?

Comment: Why do you use $css_ instead of $css?

Comment: Why not ? Is there any reason not to ? EDIT : There was an error in the question.

Comment: Why don't you just use an associative array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That probably won't just work. PHP supports full indirection though, so something like this will work.

```
$varName = $css."_".$chosen_menu;
$$varName = "value";
```

If not, it will probably be attempting to interpret `$css_` as a variable name in your second code sample, so just change that to `$css."_".$chosen_menu`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$nr = 1;        
       ${'name' . $nr} = 20 ;        
       var_dump($name1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php

You should be able to use:

```
$menu = $css . '_' .$chosen_menu;
$$menu = 'some value';
```

or

```
${$menu} = 'some value';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get you right, but how about this:

```
${$css."_".$chosen_menu} = "value";
```